# Call Sagemaker endpoint invoke_endpoint in lambda function, question for request body formats

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I have a deployed Sagemaker endpoint. When testing the endpoint using `Predictor.predict`, the endpoint works fine. I can pass down whichever Json format, it is able to process it correctly. However, I've been struggling calling endpoint from Lambda by using `client.invoke_endpoint`

I am trying to modify my request body to follow this format in this [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/cdf-inference.html).

```
let request = {
  // Instances might contain multiple rows that predictions are sought for.
  "instances": [
    {
      // Request and algorithm specific inference parameters.
      "configuration": {},
      // Data in the specific format required by the algorithm.
      "data": {
         "<field name>": dataElement
       }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not sure what should the configuration be, so this is what my request body looks like.

```
{
  "instances": [
    {
      "data": {
        "ID": "some ID",
        "ACCOUNT": null,
        "LEAD": some ID
        "FORMNAME": "some Form",
        "UTMMEDIUM": "some Medium",
        "UTMSOURCE": "some Source"
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "ID": "some ID"
        "ACCOUNT": "some ID"
        "LEAD": null,
        "FORMNAME": "some Form"
        "UTMMEDIUM": null,
        "UTMSOURCE": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my Lambda function

```
import os
import io
import boto3
import json

# grab environment variables
ENDPOINT_NAME = 'xxxxx'

client = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    payload = str(data["instances"])
    response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName = ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                      Body = payload,
                                      ContentType = 'application/json',
                                      Accept = 'application/json')
    print(response)
    return 'nothing'
```

I am able to invoke the Endpoint using the code above, but the endpoint kept having trouble processing the input. The `input_fn` in the endpoint looks like this

```
def input_fn(input_data, content_type):

    if content_type == 'text/csv':
        # Read the raw input data as CSV. 
        df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(input_data))

        return df
    
    elif content_type == 'application/json':
        print('input_fn (elif): input_data')
        print(input_data)
        print(type(input_data))
        print('input_fn (elif): input_data eval')
        print(eval(input_data))
        print('input_fn (elif): input_data eval type')
        print(type(eval(input_data)))
        df = pd.read_json(eval(input_data))
        print('input_fn (elif): df.columns')
        print(df.columns)
        return df
    
    else:
        raise ValueError("{} not supported by script!".format(content_type))
```

The error I got is`ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>`

The type of `input_data` is a string, and the type of `eval(input_data)` is a list.

I appreciate any insight! I've tried so many different things, including removing `eval` from my `input_fn`, or change `pd.json_read` to `json.loads(json.dumps())` with `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`. I've gotten different errors like `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: Line Column 42` (column 42 is where the location of null), and `unhashable type: 'dict'`

I am really confused and not sure what to to next. Thank  you!

Answer (score 0):

This would involve debugging a bit more
But I recommend replacing instances of input_data with `input_data[0]` and also try decoding since it could be byte encoded. Maybe something like this, the reason for this kind of recommendation is described at bottom and might help, **also instead of print use logging so that you can see input_data value in cloudwatch logs**

```py
input_data = (input_data[0].get('data') or input_data[0].get('body')).decode('utf-8')
```

Reason for recommendation:

In Sagemaker when using pytorch type models

- the input_data is a list and each entry corresponds to data received from some request
- The size of list will be number of request in it which also correspond to batch size in case it is using torchserve. By default batch_size is 1 in torchserve, so input_data is single element list.
- also there is chance that you get byte encoded data
- You might refer here also https://pytorch.org/serve/custom_service.html

This should help explain `ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>` and JSON decode error

Comment: @joanna-tsai can you confirm?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is in this line

```
payload = str(data["instances"])
```

You've already serialized the data, so the following code block will do justice on the boto3 invocation side as you properly decode the response.

```
#event is the test request you are sending
data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
payload = json.dumps(data)
response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                   ContentType='application/json',
                                   Body=payload)
result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode()) #decode response
```

For processing the data you want appropriate exception handling when getting a non-JSON input. Use the following code to parse the request on the Flask end.

```
input_json = flask.request.get_json()
input = input_json['input'] #whatever your input json key is
result = model.predict(input)
# Transform predictions to JSON
result = {
        'output': predictions
}
resultjson = json.dumps(result)
return flask.Response(response=resultjson, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```

I am contributing this on behalf of my employer, AWS. My contribution is licensed under the MIT license. See here for a more detailed explanation.

https://aws-preview.aka.amazon.com/tools/stackoverflow-samples-license/